# Track Order of Featured Items, Flagged With Boolean Attribute

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, ruby-on-rails-4, model, rails-activerecord

I have a Rails application with multiple `Galleries`. Each `Gallery` `has_many` `Photo`s.

A user can flag a Photo as `featured` by setting a boolean attribute on a photo. Featured photos are across all galleries, so all featured photos will sit in a single collection/list I need to:

1. Present all featured photos in a list (for use by a slideshow)
2. Allow a user to order the featured items

Getting a list of all the featured photos is easy enough using a scope on `Gallery`:

```
scope :featured, ->{ where(featured: true) }
```

But how can I track the order of the Photos and allow a user to manipulate them.

I currently allow a user to reorder images within a gallery using `acts_as_list`, which is implemented using a `position` column on `Photo`, however, this approach doesn't make sense in the case of `featured` photos as there is no `Gallery` to collect them.

**What is my best approach?**

I'm considering creating a `FeaturedPhotos` model that `has_many` `Photo`s, but I'm unclear how to translate a boolean value on the `Photo` to the act of adding/removing it from `FeaturedPhotos` or if this is a good idea. Any ideas would be appreciated.

---

Comment: Maybe look at this, acts_as_list has a :scope
http://macdiggs.com/2007/08/27/customizing-scope-in-acts_as_list/
This might be old thought.

Comment: Unless featured photos are across all the galleries ?

Comment: @rafal That's the problem. They are across all galleries.

Comment: Isn't `FeaturedPhotos` just another `Gallery`, what about instead of marking a photo as featured you mark a gallery as featured instead, the user still sees a checkbox but when clicked you also add it to 'featured' gallery. If you wanted to get really fancy you could use polymorphic associations but this may be sufficient.